# simple function to gather form data for ajax submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, form-submit

I am trying to find simple, elegant way to get all the pertinent name,value pairs from an HTML form and prepare this data for an ajax call, where the data would be saved.  I have come up with this:

```
$('#save').click(function(){
    var querystring = "";
    $('form#form_id :input').each(function(){
        querystring += $(this).attr('name') + "=" + $(this).val() + "&";
    });
    querystring = querystring.substr(0,querystring.length-1);
    alert(querystring);
});
```

I would then use this `querystring` for the update ajax script.  There are a couple problems with this:

1. all the radio button items appear in the querystring, not just the ones that are selected
2. all check boxes show up with value = "on"

Does anyone have a nice simple way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: use `.is(':checked')` not `.val()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

jQuery already has a method for it! Try this:

```
var myData = $("form#form_id").serialize();
alert(myData);
```

Plus it includes textareas and select boxes.

More info at: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#save').click(function(){
    var querystring = "";
    $('form#form_id :input').each(function(){
        querystring += $(this).attr('name') + "=" + $(this).is(":checked") + "&";
    });
    querystring = querystring.substr(0,querystring.length-1);
    alert(querystring);
});
```

Comment: I am assuming all of your `input` elements are radio buttons or check boxes, you will have to filter if that is not true